# Counting number of occurrence across lists

Tags: python, list, count

I have 3 lists with all unique elements in each and I want to count the number of occurrence for each element. Unique here means all the elements in a list are unique, no duplicated ones.

An example of the data:

```
list(c[0]):       list(c[1]):       list(c[1]):      
a                 a                 a
b                 b                 b
c                 c
d
```

And so the desired output should be

```
a:3,b:3,c:2,d:1
```

I understand that `Counter` can be applied to within one list, but how do I calculate across lists?

Comment: `Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(c))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatten the list and then use counter:

Assuming lst is  a list of the three lists in question:

```
flat = [i for sub in lst for i in sub]
Counter(flat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the 3 lists with `itertools.chain` and then use `collections.Counter` to count the items.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
c = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], ['a']]
print(dict(Counter(chain(*c))))
```

This outputs:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Comment: The overhead of unpacking a 3 element list isn't much to complain about, but `chain.from_iterable` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chain.from_iterable` to convert the list to a flat list and then feed it to `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
c = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], ['a']]
Counter(chain.from_iterable(c))
# Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})
```